# How to include the percent character in the visual studio debugger command line arguments?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, ide

I want to debug a program in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with an argument like: "file-%04d.jpg".

But entering this string in *Project Properties* > *Config Properties* > *Debugging* > *Command Arguments* changes the "%04", resulting in `argv[1]` being set to: "file-[some unknown symbol]d.jpg".

The percent character seems to be interpreted as an escape sequence which is not what I want. This does not happen in 2008.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

%xx seems to be interpreted as an ascii escape.
So %25 should result in a real % character in the argument list.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was trying to escape it with %% like in command prompt but it didn't work. This works though!

Comment: And this VS behavior is undocumented, right?